# JSON.load の symbolize_names オプションの使い方

Tags: ruby, json

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/JSON.html#M_LOAD

> :symbolize_names
>   真を指定するとハッシュのキーを文字列ではなくシンボルにします。デフォルトは偽です。

とあるんですが真にしても変わりません

```
require "json"
j = JSON.load '{"x":1}', symbolize_names: true
puts j
```

上記のようなテストコードを実行すると
`{"x"=>1}`
と出力されてしまいます

説明を読む限り
`{:x=>1}`
となるかと思ったんですがそういうものではないんでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> load(source, proc = nil, options = {}) -> object

というメソッドシグネチャーから読む限り、 options を指定するためには、第2引数を`nil`に指定しなければならないのではないか、と思っています。また、 `symbolize_names` だけだとエラーになるので、`create_additions: false` も指定する必要がある様子です。

```
JSON.load('{"x":1}', nil, symbolize_names: true, create_additions: false)
=> {:x=>1}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON.loadをJSON.parseに変更してみるのはどうでしょうか。
parseだと今書かれている引数でお望みの結果が得られると思います。